# How do I get a function to execute in a different address space? Writing a clone function

Tags: c, memory, process, malloc, clone

I have this code that gives me a segmentation fault.  My understanding of the clone function is that the parent process has to allocate space for the child process and clone calls a function that runs in that stack space.  Am I misunderstanding something or does my code just not make sense?

```
char *stack;
char *stackTop; 


    stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    if (stack == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc");
    stackTop = stack + STACK_SIZE;  
    myClone(childFunc, stackTop, CLONE_FILES, NULL);

int myClone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,int flags, void *arg){
  int* space = memcpy(child_stack, fn, sizeof(fn));
  typedef int func(void);
  func* f = (func*)&space;
  f();
}
```

Comment: Your code just does not make sense.  You cannot memcpy a function (`fn`), and expect to get all the code for that function.   Cannot be done.

Comment: How does the clone function use the stack pointer it is passed?

Comment: Why are you adding `STACK_SIZE` before you call `myClone()`? That will `memcpy` into memory that hasn't been allocated.

Comment: `sizeof(fn)` is the size of the function pointer, not the function code.

Comment: @WeatherVane how does clone use the stack pointer it is passed?

Comment: I was going to comment but @Barmar did because you are passing the top of stack instead of its bottom. You call it a stack, but memory used like this works from the lower address.

Comment: @barmar7 according to these linux man pages  "Since child and parent process may share
       memory, it is not possible for the child process to execute in the
       same stack as the calling process.  The calling process must
       therefore set up memory space for the child stack and pass a pointer
       to this space to clone().  Stacks grow downward on all processors
       that run Linux (except the HP PA processors), *** so child_stack usually
       points to the topmost address of the memory space set up for the
       child stack." *** Am I misinterpreting?

Comment: You are trying to copy the function code into the stack you created. From what you say, shouldn't you be providing a stack for the child to use? Why do you need to duplicate the function code? But I'm only making observations on what you provide: I have no idea as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WeatherVane What you said is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I don't understand to what causes the child to run in that stack space.  My intuition was that I had to move the function into that address space, which was obviously wrong.  How do I provide the stack for the child process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clone()` function is a system call. It cannot be replicated by C code running within your process.

Comment: I feel dumb.  I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons why this wouldn't work.

- Memory protection: the relevant memory pages must be executable. Data pages, you got from `malloc` are not. "Normal" memory-management functions can't do this. On the other hand, the existing code pages are not writable, so you can't move one piece of code onto another. This is a fundamental memory-protection mechanism. You have to either go back to DOS or to use some advanced "debugging" interface.
- Position-independent code: all memory addresses in your code must be either relative ones, or be fixuped manually. It may be too tricky to do this in C.

Answer (score 0):

There's a *fundamental* misunderstanding there. So you're getting a *segmentation fault*, that tells me you're trying to run this code in *user space* (in a process created by the operating system).

An *address space* is an abstraction available to the operating system. It typically uses hardware support (that of an *MMU* [memory management unit]) which provides means to use *virtual* addresses. These are addresses that are, when accessed, automatically translated to the real *physical* addresses according to some data structures that only the OS can manage.

I don't think it makes much sense to go into great detail here, you have enough key words to google for. The essence is: There is **no way** you can create an *address space* from *user space* code. That functionality is reserved to the OS and to do it, `clone()` on linux issues a *syscall*, invoking the OS.

*edit*: concerning the stack, providing a stack means to reserve space for it (by mapping an appropriate amount of pages to the address space) *and* setting the necessary processor registers when context is switched to the process (e.g. `esp`/`ebp` on `i386`). This, too, is something only the operating system can do.